# Scala Option something like flatMap but for None case?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scala-cats

I have an `Option[A]` and I want to say: If it's a `None` then computes another `Option[A]`, otherwise stay as is. `getOrElse[A]` accepts an `A` (I need to pass an `Option[A]`) and `flatMap` applies to the `Some` case (I want to handle the `None` case) . Essentially I want the following code but in the most succinct way possible:

```scala
val a: Option[A] = ???
a match {
  case None => ??? // returns an Option[A] here 
  case Some(x) => a
}
```

Comment: `orElse` As I always say, the [**Scaladoc**](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Option.html) is your friend!

Answer (score 1):

This is embarrassing.

For other lazy people out there like myself the answer is [`orElse`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.6/scala/Option.html#orElse%5BB%3E:A%5D(alternative:=%3EOption%5BB%5D):Option%5BB%5D)